# How can I print one (different) part of a list every time a conditional statement is met?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops

So I have a function that basically prompts the user to find a certain predetermined number (76/seventy-six). Every time an incorrect guess is made, they are given a hint followed by the option to guess again. I want to be able to give them different hints from my list for each incorrect guess. This is also tricky because I have to have a set number of hints, so after the list is exhausted the user should just be prompted to guess again without guidance. I haven't yet come up with my hints, but here is the code:

```
hint_list = ['filler_1','filler_2', 'filler_3', 'filler_4', 'filler_5']

def try_and_respond():
    guess = raw_input('Guess: ')
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess = int(guess)
        correct = guess == 76
    else:
        correct = guess.lower() == 'seventy-six'
    if correct:
        print '\n\033[1;36;40m Fantastic! 76 is correct.'
    elif not correct:
        print '\n\033[1;31;40mIncorrect. Here is a hint: \033[1;30;47m'
        print hint_list[0]
        try_and_respond()
```

Comment: Should it be random? Or simply cycle through starting at the beginning, in the same order?

Comment: @orlp Same order

Comment: Is there none of the two answers that are satisfying?
If none is satisfying please comment, so that you can get better answers.
If you have satisfying answers, then please upvote / accept.

If too many users with low reputation don't accept answers, then there is the risk that more and more people will not help users with a low reputation, which would be a pity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter to decide which hint to show next.

If you want to have hints in random order use random.shuffle()

```
# import random  # uncomment if random hint order
hint_list = ['filler_1','filler_2', 'filler_3', 'filler_4', 'filler_5']

# uncomment next line for random hint order
# random.shuffle(hint_list)

incorrect_count = 0
def try_and_respond():
    global incorrect_count
    guess = raw_input('Guess: ')
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess = int(guess)
        correct = guess == 76
    else:
        correct = guess.lower() == 'seventy-six'
    if correct:
        print '\n\033[1;36;40m Fantastic! 76 is correct.'
    else:
        if incorrect_count < len(hint_list):
            print '\n\033[1;31;40mIncorrect. Here is a hint: \033[1;30;47m'
            print hint_list[incorrect_count]
            incorrect_count += 1
        try_and_respond()

try_and_respond()
```

And here a modified version without recursion, but an explicit loop instead and some code to make the code python3 compatible, but let it still run with python2

```
# import random  # uncomment if random hint order
import sys

# It's 2020, So I suggest to
# make the code also python 3 compatible.
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    input = raw_input

hint_list = ['filler_1','filler_2', 'filler_3', 'filler_4', 'filler_5']

# uncomment next line for random hint order
# random.shuffle(hint_list)

incorrect_count = 0
def try_and_respond():
    global incorrect_count
    guess = input('Guess: ')
    if guess.isdigit():
        guess = int(guess)
        correct = guess == 76
    else:
        correct = guess.lower() == 'seventy-six'
    if correct:
        print('\n\033[1;36;40m Fantastic! 76 is correct.')
    else:
        if incorrect_count < len(hint_list):
            print('\n\033[1;31;40mIncorrect. Here is a hint: \033[1;30;47m')
            print(hint_list[incorrect_count])
            incorrect_count += 1
    return correct

while not try_and_respond():
    try_and_respond()
```

Comment: please note, that your code is 'a little strange' 
Idtdoesn't use a loop, but recursion to prompt for further times
In my answer I just adressed the way of the hint list and dodn't touch the rest of the code.

I might edit my answer laterom to add a modified version of your script, that I consider more common

Comment: just replaced: `print hint_list[0]` with `print hint_list[incorrect_count]` my bad

Comment: Just read your answer to @orlp

If you don'twant random order and stop giving hints, then just remove the `import random` and the `random.shuffle(hint_list)` from my answer

Answer (score 0):

To cycle a set of values it's often easy to use the modulo `%` operator.

Try out the following:

```
hint_idx = 0
while True:
    print(hints[hint_idx])
    hint_idx = (hint_idx + 1) % len(hints)
```

Comment: I think the OP asked to show each hint and to then stop giving hints.

Still good to show the modulo  operator though. Other people reading this question might want to cycle through perhaps.